# Download/install code from github for python?

Tags: python, github

So I do not really understand *what* github is, but I would like to implement the function described in this paper: 
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4717949

where the github files are uploaded here: 
https://github.com/SantiagoEG/FCBF_module

I am very new to python, and am at a loss for how to be able to use this without copying/pasting their function into my notebook.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the files, simply run

```
git clone https://github.com/SantiagoEG/FCBF_module
```

in a terminal.

Alternatively, you can [download a zip](https://github.com/SantiagoEG/FCBF_module/archive/master.zip) directly from the GitHub UI.

[image]